# Random Number Generator: Should it be used as a singleton?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, random, c++03

I use random numbers in several places and usually construct a random number generator whenever I need it. Currently I use the Marsaglia Xorshift algorithm  seeding it with the current system time. 
Now I have some doubts about this strategy:
If I use several generators the independence (randomness) of the numbers between the generators depends on the seed (same seed same number). Since I use the time (ns) as seed and since this time changes this works but I am wondering whether it would not be better to use only one singular generator and e.g. to make it available as a singleton. Would this increase the random number quality ?

Edit: Unfortunately c++11 is not an option yet

Edit: To be more specific: I am not suggesting that the singleton could increase the random number quality but the fact that only one generator is used and seeded. Otherwise I have to be sure that the seeds of the different generators are independent (random) from another. 
Extreme example: I seed two generators with exactly the same number -> no randomness between them

Comment: Just throwing C++11's `<random>` out there.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on an embedded target -> no c++11 :-/

Comment: You could always use the output of a first RNG to seed subsequent ones. That would effectively make them one generator, but without the hassle of global state.

Comment: @Martin embedded target does not imply no c++11.

Comment: @juanchopanza: True, but mine does: The compiler is a fork of gcc but this one does not comply with most of the new standard so we have decided to not switch to c++11 yet for the software on this target and this decision is binding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have several variables, each of which needs to be random, independent from the others, and will be regularly reassigned with a new random value from some random generator. This happens quite often with Monte Carlo analysis, and games (although the rigor for games is much less than it is for Monte Carlo). If a perfect random number generator existed, it would be fine to use a single instantiation of it. Assign the *n*<sup>th</sup> pseudo random number from the generator to variable *x*<sub>1</sub>, the next random number to variable *x*<sub>2</sub>, the next to *x*<sub>3</sub>, and so on, eventually coming back to variable *x*<sub>1</sub> on the next cycle. around. There's a problem here: Far too many PRNGs fail the independence test fail the independence test when used this way, some even fail randomness tests on individual sequences.

My approach is to use a single PRNG generator as a seed generator for a set of *N* instances of self-contained PRNGs. Each instance of these latter PRNGs feeds a single variable. By self-contained, I mean that the PRNG is an object, with state maintained in instance members rather than in static members or global variables. The seed generator doesn't even need to be from the same family as those other *N* PRNGs. It just needs to be reentrant in the case that multiple threads are simultaneously trying to use the seed generator. However, In my uses I find that it is best to set up the PRNGs before threading starts so as to guarantee repeatability. That's one run, one execution. Monte Carlo techniques typically need thousands of executions, maybe more, maybe a lot more. With Monte Carlo, repeatability is essential. So yet another a random seed generator is needed. This one seeds the seed generator used to generate the *N* generators for the variables.

Repeatability is important, at least in the Monte Carlo world. Suppose run number 10234 of a long Monte Carlo simulation results in some massive failure. It would be nice to see what in the world happened. It might have been a statistical fluke, it might have been a problem. The problem is that in a typical MC setup, only the bare minimum of data are recorded, just enough for computing statistics. To see what happened in run number 10234, one needs to repeat that particular case but now record everything.

Comment: Interesting approach. I totally agree on the point of repeatability. In short you increase the randomness by creating the seed from a former random number generator which sounds elegant. Do you warm up the generators as well ? Some need a few iterations until producing good distributions. The single first order random number generator must however be accessible for the other peers (e.g. as singleton) and to ensure the repeatability I would have to make sure that the initialization order of the second order generators remains constant

Comment: That initialization order problem is why it's a good idea to create and seed those second order generators before you start creating threads. Repeatability can be very important. Regarding the randomness, well there is no guarantee. Not really. This approach just does a better job. The idea is that if you have a PRNG with an extremely long period, what that random seed does is to (hopefully) place the second tier generators very far from one another in terms of that very long underlying sequence, (hopefully) bettering the odds that the  subsequences will be independent.

Comment: Agree with this approach. My only suggestion is that you use a set of sequential numbers for the initial seeds rather than use an RNG to generate them. This gurantees that each seed is different. It probably would not be a problem for most RNGs (e.g. simple LCG) since they have long periods, but given that there is no advatange to the seeds themselves being random, I would suggest this as best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the same instance of your random generator class whenever the clients are interrelated and the code needs "independent" random number.

You can use different objects of your random generator class when the clients do not depend on each other and it does not matter whether they receive the same numbers or not.

Note that for testing and debugging it is very useful to be able to create the same sequence of random numbers again. Therefore you should not "randomly seed" too much.

Comment: Yes, you should use the same insttance, but what if the calls to random are very deep in the call tree? How do you get that instance to its calling site? That's why the OP suggested a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that its increasing the randomness but it reduces the memory you need to create an object every time you want to use the random generator. If this generator doesn't have any instance specific settings you can make a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

> Since I use the time (ns) as seed and since this time changes this works but I am wondering whether it would not be better to use only one singular generator and e.g. to make it available as a singleton.

This is a good example when the singleton is not an anti-pattern. You could also use some kind of [inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).

> Would this increase the random number quality ?

No. The quality depends on the algorithm that generate random numbers. How you use it is irrelevant (assuming it is used correctly).

To your edit : you could create some kind of container that holds objects of your RNG classes (or use existing containers). Something like this :

```
std::vector< Rng > & RngSingleton()
{
  static std::vector< Rng > allRngs( 2 );
  return allRngs;
}

struct Rng
{
  void SetSeed( const int seen );
  int GenerateNumber() const;
//...
};

// ...
RngSingleton().at(0).SetSeed( 55 );
RngSingleton().at(1).SetSeed( 55 );
//...
const auto value1 = RngSingleton().at(0).GenerateNumber;
const auto value2 = RngSingleton().at(1).GenerateNumber;
```

Comment: I think I need to be more specific: I was not suggesting that the singleton could increase the random number quality but the fact that only one generator is used and seeded. Otherwise I have to be sure that the seeds of the different generators are independent (random) from another. Extreme example: I seed two generators with exactly the same number -> identical results

Comment: There are no particular problems related to singletons in this case.  Using a single generator is probably preferable, and a singleton is the simplest way to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

Factory pattern to the rescue.
A client should never have to worry about the instantiation rules of its dependencies. 
It allows for swapping creation methods. And the other way around, if you decide to use a different algorithm you can swap the generator class and the clients need no refactoring.
http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html

--EDIT

Added pseudocode (sorry, it's not c++, it's waaaaaay too long ago since I last worked in it)

```
interface PRNG{
    function generateRandomNumber():Number;
}

interface Seeder{
    function getSeed() : Number;
}

interface PRNGFactory{
    function createPRNG():PRNG;
}

class MarsagliaPRNG implements PRNG{
    constructor( seed : Number ){
        //store seed
    }

    function generateRandomNumber() : Number{
        //do your magic
    }
}

class SingletonMarsagliaPRNGFactory implements PRNGFactory{
    var seeder : Seeder;
    static var prng : PRNG;
    function createPRNG() : PRNG{
        return prng ||= new MarsagliaPRNG( seeder.getSeed() );
    }
}

class TimeSeeder implements Seeder{
    function getSeed():Number{
        return now();
    }
}

//usage:
seeder : Seeder = new TimeSeeder();
prngFactory : PRNGFactory = new SingletonMarsagliaPRNGFactory();

clientA.prng = prngFactory.createPRNG();
clientB.prng = prngFactory.createPRNG();
//both clients got the same instance.
```

The big advantage is now that if you want/need to change any of the implementation details, nothing has to change in the clients. You can change seeding method, RNG algorithm and the instantiation rule w/o having to touch any client anywhere.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this ? IMHO even a factory that includes some internal state (like an RNG) and is globally accessible would be sth. like a singleton. I do not see how a factory can improve the random number generation

Comment: -1. This doesn't answer the question. A factory that creates different PRNGs that use different algorithms is a bit irrelevant as the algorithm is fixed (Marsaglia's Xorshift) and isn't going to help address the seeding problem. It doesn't deal with the nasty realities of pseudo random number generators. PRNGs are leaky, very leaky because what is desired and what can be provided are very different things. Consider the problem of a random number between 0 and 1. Can't do it, not really, because a number from U[0,1] is a noncomputable number. The best that can be done is a mere facsimile.

Comment: Ummm... I didn't mean to have a factory create PRNG with different algorithms. I added pseudocode to my answer to clarify what I meant.
If it's still not clear, let me know.